# Mockito unit testing: on all method invocations of a class, return "true"

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I have a class in kotlin `SmsHandler`, with a method `determineFiltersPass` that invokes methods of another class, `SmsSendingFilters`:

```
class SmsHandler(val filterPredicates: SmsSendingFilters) {
    fun determineFiltersPass(sms: SmsDto): Boolean = with(sms.filters) {
        var pass = true
        for (filter in FiltersDto::class.memberProperties)
            pass = when (FilterType.valueOf(filter.name.toUpperCase())) {
                UNIQUE -> if (filter.get(sms.filters) != null) {
                    val unique = filter.get(sms.filters) as Boolean
                    pass && if (unique) filterPredicates.isUnique().test(sms) else true
                } else pass && true
                RECENT -> if (filter.get(sms.filters) != null) {
                    pass && filterPredicates.shouldSendByTimePeriodFromLastMessage().test(sms)
                } else pass && true
                else -> pass && true
            }
        pass
    }
}


class SmsSendingFilters {

    fun isUnique(): Predicate<SmsDto> = Predicate {
        with(it) {
        repo.findAllByMessageIdAndMobileNumAndAppIdAndParamMap(messageId!!, mobileNum!!, appId!!, paramMap!!.toString()).isEmpty()
        }
    }

    fun shouldSendByTimePeriodFromLastMessage(): Predicate<SmsDto> = Predicate {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = Date()
        with(it.filters.recent ?: "" to "") {
            val size = this.second.toInt()
            when (IntervalType.valueOf(this.first.toUpperCase())) {
                SECOND -> calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1 * size)
                MINUTE -> calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1 * size)
                HOUR -> calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1 * size)
                MONTH -> calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1 * size)
                YEAR -> calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1 * size)
                else -> Unit
            }
            with(it) {
                repo.findAllByMessageIdAndMobileNumAndAppId(messageId!!, mobileNum!!, appId!!)
                    .none { it.dateSent?.toInstant()?.isAfter(calendar.toInstant()) ?: true }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm testing the class `SmsHandler` and because I predict that more filters will be added to the second class, I want to create a generic mock that on invocation of any method from class `SmsSendingFilters`, will return `true` or `false` as I please. Is there a way of doing so without describing the invocation of each method name explicitly (through reflection I guess)?

I'm not looking for a solution of sort:

```
when(filterPredicates.shouldSendByTimePeriodFromLastMessage().test(any()).thenReturn(true)
```

But, something that complies with this logic:

```
when(filterPredicates.<anyMethodInvoked>().test(any())).thenReturn(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can register an `Answer` to change the default return value](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#defaultreturn).

For example (using the excellent [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) wrapper):

```
interface Thingy {
    fun foo() : Boolean
    fun bar() : Boolean
}

class ThingyTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val t1 = mock<Thingy>(defaultAnswer = Answer { false })
        println(t1.foo())   // "false"
        println(t1.bar())   // "false"

        val t2 = mock<Thingy>(defaultAnswer = Answer { true })
        println(t2.foo())   // "true"
        println(t2.bar())   // "true"
    }
}
```

Of course, in a more complex case you may have methods that return different types, in which case you'd need to do something smarter in your `Answer` implementation!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try It tomorrow at work :D